# android: Is it possible to disable notifications of other apps (facebook, instagram) for a certain period of time from my own app use Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

In my code I displayed list apps installed on Android I want to turn off notifications for this list during certain time intervals from my own app.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I certainly hope it is NOT possible. Its not an accident that Apple and Google keep each app isolated. And notifications are an especially touchy area. The OS is designed to protect users against malicious apps. Any potentially useful ability has to be weighed against the possibility of abuse. Sorry, there is no way this will be possible ever, on any device.

Comment: The intention of this application is not bad, it is only to turn off notifications for a specific period of time to study (it is a university project only).@ToolmakerSteve

Comment: It is impossible to implement this , we have to manually turn off notifications in Settings during certain time intervals .

Comment: @Aya - I was not suggesting that your app had any bad intention. I was explaining the decision-making process of OS designers, who have to design for the worst case (malicious apps). Do Not Disturb might be an option (if newer Android versions allow to set programmatically). google `android do not disturb set programmatically`.